# How to get those Asian characters back on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, internationalization

One of my Java Eclipse projects is moved to my new pc. All Chinese characters on files become squares in Eclipse. The text file encoding of the Eclipse resource is utf-8, the same as what it was in my old pc.

How to let The Chinese characters be displayed correctly?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a text encoding problem with UTF-8 but a question of whether the font on the computer contains the characters you need.

I would suggest locating an already installed or installing a good monospaced font containing the characters you need and then switch the editor font to that.

Comment: @ I already thought a possible cause on OS. Here is my test: I tried Chinese characters in Open office and saved the file. Those characters are shown as what they are in the saved file. The result of this test seems to me that isn't on an OS level.

Comment: Eclipse uses a font which doesn't have the characters you need. Change the font in eclipse.

Comment: I get it works although I don't like the SimSun nor SimHei font.

Comment: Great.  Now you just need a font you like.  Would this be because it is a US-English Windows in e.g. a Home Edition?  To my understanding, western versions of Windows come with reduced fonts.  You may be able to install additional font packs from Microsoft.